# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed , django

Tags: python, django

I have to insert the post through a form but when i submit i got this error FOREIGN KEY constraint failed, the problem is with the author field

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('published','Published'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',related_name='blog_posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    body = RichTextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft')
    tag = models.OneToOneField(Tag,related_name="blog_tag",on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def tagView(request,name):
    tag = Tag.objects.get(name=name)
    post_form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            item = post_form.save(commit=False)
            item.author = request.user
            item.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
    context = {
        'post_form' : post_form,
        'tag' : tag,
    }
    return render(request,'blog/tagPage.html',context)
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','body']
```

template

```
<form class="post-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ post_form }}
    <input class="post-form-submit submit" type="submit" value="Save">
  </form>
```

Comment: Show the full error. Are you sure author is the problem?

Comment: the `tag` attribute must be set when saving a `Post` instance, but neither your form nor your view define it.

Answer (score 0):

If the author field is the problem, be sure to import auth.User

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to add the post as anonymous but anonymous user is not null (id is though). Also don't use `'auth.User'` and follow the instructions from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).